# React-Native sleep function for API call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I'm making two different Fetch via my website API in the same react native component. The first FETCH call will return list1 and the second one will return list2 then I display those two list in 2 different FlatList. I chose to put in a state the second list in order to re-render my component only one time.
As it is asynchronous, sometimes, I can see when the component is mounted list1 is null. I'm wondering if I need to add a sleep until list1 got his value (I don't know how to do that) or do I need to put the second API call in ComponentDidMount (I tried it but it seems the same). Is there any solution for that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use a fetch function

Comment: It's generally considered bad practice to block the entire UI when waiting for a portion of the required data to load.  A common approach would be to conditionally render a spinner in place of each list until the data is loaded.